# How to build an app with Material Ui with chunk splitting?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I have an app on **react**, I am using **Material Ui**. After the build, I see in the source a lot of **Material Ui** code in `<style>` tag. But I want to use chunks and connect **Material Ui** styles via `<link>`. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried and the link of the app if possible if not just include a screenshot because i have never faced such an issue

Comment: @GayatriDipali updated post. Added image. This is what I see in head tag. I want to move this to chunks and just connect css file